# Trying to understand GSM-7 and GSM-8

Tags: encoding, sms, gsm

I'm working on texting and I want to understand the SMS encoding sets. I've read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38 but those sets seem crazy to me:

1. GSM-7 wastes precious space including Greek letters
2. GSM-7 includes Ç but not ç
3. GSM-8 could define 128 chars but instead defines only 12: that's a huge waste of space!

They could have easily fitted all useful chars for all latin languages, at least in GSM-8, but instead they decided to waste a lot of space and as a result, you often need to use UCS-2 which means texts need to be split for many people. For example, if you use 'ç' in French, you need to use UCS-2; if you use the common Spanish letter ó in the US, you need UCS-2 as well.

Can anybody restore my faith in the people that invented this and give me a good reason why those sets are like that?

Comment: Its all from the history. First it was gsm7 alphabet on Paging devices. 160 chars max.
Then GSM was invented, and put same protocol for SMS messages. Later they extended GSM7 table (with special ESC char to look into 2nd table). It was not enough, so they did GSM8 After spread of mobile phones to all over the world UCS2 was used to support other languages as well. Its all because of back-compatibility thru history. New SMS's will be thru SIP which is more open.

Comment: I understand all that, what I don't understand is the choice of chars and why is most of GSM8 empty...

Comment: What do you mean with empty ? GSM8 is raw, 255 chars, its up to phone how it will handle it. Language specific tables are in UCS-2 and GSM7 with shifting, altough in this case not all languages are yet defined properly if thats what you mean.

Comment: GSM8 allows to define 128 more chars, but it only defines 10-12. They could easily have filled that space with all latin alphabets chars (Spanish, French, Portuguese, German, even probably Polish, etc.), that way those languages would almost never have to encode texts in UCS2 and could send texts with a 140 chars limit instead of 70.

Comment: You're mixing GSM7 and GSM8. GSM7 by default have extended table with few more characters. GSM8 has 256 characters. Beside you can use UTF-8 which most phones will handle. For example, only two bytes, like 0xc3, 0x9f for ß. Its still 8bit (not 16 as UCS-2). So ßa is 0xc3,0x9f,0x41 (3 bytes only)

Comment: Indeed I was mixing them, so treat my questions replacing "GSM8" by "extended set of GSM7"... the questions still remain! Also, phones might handle UTF8, but when you send the text to the carrier, it will encode using GSM7, extended or UCS2. For example, if you have a text 71 chars long with one ó then the carrier will bill 2 SMS. If it had used UTF8, you could have easily used only one SMS.

Comment: Phones are set by vendors, many of them are not following the 3GPP standards at all. Even iPhone :)  So its up to phone kernel, how it will transmit or receive SMS.
Regarding GSM7 not all countries participate in evolving extended tables. I remember, they had lots of problems with France those days. So the idea was good while achievement not :) Anyway not all language can fit into ext.table so its extended by some languages (e.g. spanish,turkish...) So you need country participating,translator,standard promotor and phone vendors to have incorporated which is hard...